# Understanding implicitly declared default costructor

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I'm trying to understand how the compiler's default constructor works. I made this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
    int number;
};

class Test1 : public Base {  
};

class Test2 {
    public:
    Base base;
};

int main() {
    Test1 test1;
    Test2 test2;
    std::cout<<test1.number<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<test2.base.number<<std::endl;
}
```

The output of this test program is, for `test1` `0`, and for `test2` is a uninitialized (random) number. Now my question is: why in the first case (`test1`) the compiler's default constructor initialize `number` to `0` but for `test2` it doesn't?

**Edit**: According to answers both makes undefined behavior. So, in this program, what the compiler's default constructor does?

Comment: The value of `number` is unspecified in both cases. Furthermore, reading from it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza so it's just a case that, after 10 times i ran the program, test1.number is always 0?

Comment: Right, you can't rely on your program doing anything, really.

Comment: @juanchopanza i have edited my question to ask this: so if it does not initialize the variables, what does the default constructor actually does?

Comment: @Juanchopanza, I think you mean that it is *indeterminate* in both cases. *Unspecified* means that it has a valid value, we just don't know what it is (and therefore would be safe to read).

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of an uninitialized object is *indeterminate* as per 8.5/12:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced (5.17).

Unfortunately for you, `int` falls into the category of "non-default-initialized types" as per §8.5/7:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Comment: so primitive types (like int) will not be initialized until i explicit initialize them?

Comment: @WileTheCoyot, exactly, sir.

Comment: @WileTheCoyot or if you instantiate a container full of `Base`, `Test1` or `Test2`. If any of those types are *value initilized*, the int gets zero initialized.

Comment: @Jefffrey can you give me the paper when you found that?

Comment: It is from the C++ standard. You have to pay to get it; however public drafts from the standard development process are freely available and very similar. Google for "n3337" for example.

Comment: @WileTheCoyot, yes, of course: you can find them [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft). The one I've checked is the N3936 one (the final draft of the C++14 standard), but I'm sure any other/older draft will contain the same statement.

Answer (score 3):

Actually in both cases `number` is non-default-initialized, meaning its value could be anything. It just so happened that test1 output 0 instead of some random number.

Comment: Actually, sir, I can't find any mention to undefined behavior in the standard. Can you?

Comment: In [conv.lval], "A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to a prvalue. 53 If T is an incomplete
type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If the object to which the glvalue refers is not
an object of type T and is not an object of a type derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, a program
that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior."

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I can never remember what the implicitly defined default constructor does except in the simplest cases.  So I only rely on it for the simplest cases.

I took a look at the [C++11 January working paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (i.e., an edited version of the Standard published after the Standard was approved). Section 12.1 paragraph 6 (p. 243) states, "The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer and an empty compound-statement."

If I understand "ctor-initializer" and "compound-statement" correctly, your implicitly defined constructors are:

```
Test1::Test1() {}

Test2::Test2() {}

Base::Base() {}
```

So, in both `Test1` and `Test2`, `Base::number` is never initialized (`Base` is, in `Test2`, but `Base`'s implicit constructor doesn't initialize `number`).

At least, the Standard doesn't require that `Base::number` be initialized.  Compilers are free to define things that the Standard doesn't define.  The fact that you see a `0` doesn't mean the operation is defined according to the Standard, it simply means your compiler zeroed things out in this particular case.

Comment: does the pdf you linked refers to the current c++11 standard?

Comment: You can buy a copy of the Standard from ISO or from member bodies.  It's not cheap, although the price has dropped (I believe the US member body charges $500).  The PDF I linked to is a copy of what the Standard looked like just before it was approved ( http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11#cpp11-what ).

Comment: @MaxLybbert: N3337 (the linked to PDF) is dated 2012. The draft I use for referring to C++11 standard is N3290, which was the final draft, no changes added in the C++11 standard. Unfortunately it was sort of "revoked", as I recall, in the sense that it's no longer a freely available document.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Thanks for that explanation.  I've always just grabbed whatever Wikipedia links to, so I didn't know there was a story behind the scenes this time around.  I've edited my description of N3337.