# Why default constructor is called when I create an array of objects, but errors out when I create obj as simple variable?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am aware that default constructor (possibly implicit) is called when array of objects is created.
However, getting an error when I try to inspect public variables of default initialized object.

```
class Base {
public: 
    int number;
    //Base(int a, int b) {} // inhibits creation of def. ctor
};

Base b; 
//std::cout << b.number << std::endl;
// prev line generates error:
// Error 3 error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used

Base a[10];
// prints garbage, no errors
std::cout << a[0].number << std::endl;

Base *p = new Base[10];
// prints garbage, no errors
std::cout << p[0].number << std::endl;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22795079/465292 notes that `int falls into the category of "non-default-initialized types" as per §8.5/7:`

So, obviously for array types, implicit constructor is called on individual elements. In light of previous sentence, why `std::cout << a[0].number << std::endl;` generated no errors ? (Using Visual Studio 2013 professional edition)

EDIT:
Here is output from Intel C++ compiler

```
1>Source.cpp(37): warning #592: variable "a" is used before its value is set
1>      std::cout << a[0].number << std::endl;
1>                   ^
1>  
1>  xilink: executing 'link'
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It prints garbage as well. At least it gives a warning, unlike VS compiler.

Comment: Both of those last two are undefined behaviour. I'm not sure what's up with MSVC if it's complaining about `b` instead of `b.number`.

Comment: C4700 isn't an error it's a warning. Perhaps you have warnings as errors enabled.

Comment: @chris, it is obvious that if it prints garbage, it is `undefined`

Comment: C++ doesn't guarantee error messages for most errors. When you get an actual error message, count yourself lucky.

Comment: Although It seems, the default constructor does not initialize `int` both in normal variable and in array. I think it's your compiler problem that compiler cannot recongize uninitialize value in array- Have you tried it on other compiler? (e.g. g++)

Comment: @newprint, You're asking why there's no error. I'm saying it's undefined behaviour. It doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: @ikh Intel C++ compiler 1>Source.cpp(37): warning #592: variable "a" is used before its value is set
1>     std::cout << a[0].number << std::endl;
1>                  ^
1>  
1>  xilink: executing 'link'
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
But prints garbage as well.

Comment: FWIW, neither g++ nor clang++ warn either.

Comment: Compilers vary in the amount of effort they make to analyze your code and produce warnings.

Comment: This code and question are rubbish. Default constructors are not called when an array of objects is created. Accessing unitialised objects is Undefined Behaviour. The VS sample uses pointer `p` but is compared to Intel sample using static?/local? `a`. There is nothing left worth answering.

Comment: @ikh there is no such thing as "default constructor" for primitive types.  There are three categories of initialization: *default*, *value* and *zero*. For `int` with no initializer specified, these mean *no initialization*, `0`, `0` respectively.  Uninitialized automatic variables fall under *default* initialization.

Comment: @MattMcNabb you seem to misunderstand; I'm saying about the default constructor of *class Base*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not an error; it is a warning. It is informing you that your `Base`, which is a POD, has only members which have not been initialised.

The compiler is not capable in the general case of emitting this warning in your other examples. However, in all cases where you access `number`, you are breaking the contract of the language because that variable has an unspecified value. You say it outputs "garbage" and I'm not clear on why you expected any different; you gave it no meaningful value, so it has no meaningful value. Such is the nature of things. It also means that this means your program has *undefined behaviour* and you need to fix it.

Get that constructor uncommented and invoke it, use aggregate initialisation (using `{}`), or manually assign a value to that `number` member *before* you attempt to read from it.

Comment: `That is not an error; it is a warning.`: Not so for the OP, dues to his pragmas / compiler options. Anyway, that's at most a minor pedantic-mode nitpick.